# How to represent days and time graphically for a project I have done

Tags: project-management, time-management, waterfall

How to represent the days and hours of different tasks(design, development, testing) of a software project in a graphical way.

I tried using a Gantt chart for it, but it does not represent the hours but just days, of a particular task, in a project.

Is there any way to do this in software management, I need this to show it to a client for a project I did.

Here is some of the values I intend to use.

```
●   Research time
   ○    Days 10 - 8 hours * 10 = 80
●   Design time 
   ○    Days 10 -8 hours * 10 = 80
●   Development time
   ○    Days 15 – 8 hours times 15 = 120     
●   Testing time
   ○    Days 3 – 8 hours times 3 = 24
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Programmers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery). They offer many many different types of chart formats. From researching all the available charts, you might be able to find one that will offer what you need.

The Advanced Example of the [timeline chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#AdvancedExample) might be something you can adapt to what you need. You may be able to colour code:

- Research time
- Design time
- Development time
- Testing time

Have have multiple charts per task.